# In Microsoft Excel, is there a way to dynamically change a column width based upon cell contents without using visual basic?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Is it possible to dynamically change a column width based upon cell contents without using visual basic?

For example, if I place a 1 in cell A1, I want to collapse the B and C columns by setting them to a zero width. See the image below.

[image: Excel Sample]

Or if I place a 1 in cell B1, I would want to collapse the A and C columns, etc.

I can easily use an IF() statement to test the cell contents, but I cannot find a function which will change the properties of a cell.

I can also use conditional formatting to change certain properties of a cell, but cannot find a way to change the width of the column.

Is what I am wanting to do possible without using visual basic and active x controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional formatting is limited to modifying the data type of the cell, the font features, the border, and the fill of the cell.

Modifying the size of the row or column is not one of the options in Conditional Formatting.

Therefore, to do what you ask, you would have to use VBA/Macro.